# what is wrong with this code in projectEuler 10?

Tags: java, project

i wrote this code for [project Euler problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10) . but in line 24 it has an error. how to fix it?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int b = 2000;
    List<Integer> notPrime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    notPrime.add(2);
    notPrime.add(3);
    notPrime.add(5);
    notPrime.add(7);
    for (i = 2; i < b; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 && i % 7 != 0) {
            notPrime.add(i);
        }
    }

    for(int primesNum:notPrime){
        int dd = (int) Math.pow(primesNum, 2);
        int indexofdd = Arrays.asList(notPrime).indexOf(dd); 
        //here is the error
        notPrime.remove(indexofdd);
    }
         int summy = notPrime.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
         System.out.println(summy);
}
```

Comment: ...and what is the error?

Comment: `(int) Math.pow(primesNum, 2)` is more easily written as `primesNum * primesNum`.

Comment: Note: you can skip all the even numbers instead of checking `i % 2 != 0` ie.e. `i = 3` and `i += 2` You can also skip all the multiples of 3 as well but that is trickier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `Arrays.asList(notPrime)` is `List<List<Integer>>`, meaning that `Arrays.asList(notPrime).indexOf(<some int>)` is always going to be -1 (not found), because a `List<List<Integer>>` cannot contain an `Integer`.

Hence the call to `List.remove` will fail, since as the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) states:

> Throws IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`.

You can simply write:

```
notPrime.remove(Integer.valueOf(dd));
```

(No need for separate `indexOf` call)

You need the `Integer.valueOf` in order to ensure that `List.remove(Object)` is invoked, rather than `List.remove(int)`: the latter removes the element at the given index, whereas the former removes the list element with the given value.

However, the logic of this code looks more generally faulty.